# Failed to deserialize RPC reply, Requested interfaces must consist only of methods that start with 'get', [corda] errorCode 15rlwi0

Tags: corda

I am playing around with a small project derived from here: https://github.com/corda/cash-issuer.

This repo is building on unreleased corda 4.0 version (Snapshot).
I've written a small script to issue cash via rpc client, which worked fine.
I can query the vault from the interactive shell and get the correct result:

```
run vaultQuery contractStateType: net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash$State
states:
- state:
    data: !<net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash$State>
      amount: "10000.00 EUR issued by O=PartyA, L=New York, C=US[01]"
...
```

However, it fails to do the same query in an api hosted in the integrated webserver:

```
@GET
@Path("balances")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
fun getBalances() : List<Cash.State> {
    return rpcOps.vaultQueryBy<Cash.State>().states.map{it.state.data}
}
```

fails with

```
[ERROR] 19:21:57+0100 [Thread-3 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.artemisMessageHandler - Failed to deserialize RPC body [errorCode=15rlwi0, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0-SNAPSHOT/15rlwi0]
Failed to deserialize RPC reply: net.corda.core.utilities.Try$Success (erased) -> value(*) -> net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash$State: Requested interfaces must consist only of methods that start with 'get': net.corda.core.contracts.FungibleAsset.withNewOwnerAndAmount
```

I'm on a windows10, nothing special.

Comment: This issue seems related: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-2330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tbltzk notes, this is a bug that was fixed as part of r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-2330.

Corda's snapshot releases undergo less testing than official releases, and are thus more likely to contain bugs.